# How can I convert this where I only get the information I need?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

[image]

I have a PowerShell script that pulls all the OS versions of Azure cloud services and writes it to a CSV file. It does what I want, but I just want the WA-Guest piece without the @{}. Would I need to convert it into a string from a PowerShell object first then write it into my custom object?

Edit for Theo:

```
    function CreateCustomObject{
    Param(
        [string]$Subscription, 
        [string]$cloudServiceName,
        [string]$osVersion        
    )
    #$instanceObj = $null
    $instanceObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $instanceObj | Add-Member -Name "DateOfReport" -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $date
    $instanceObj | Add-Member -Name "Subscription" -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $Subscription
    $instanceObj | Add-Member -Name "CloudServiceName" -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $cloudServiceName
    $instanceObj | Add-Member -Name "OSVersion" -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $osVersion
    return $instanceObj
}

##############################################################################

Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Credential

# Gets an array of the subscription names 
$subs = (Get-AzureSubscription)

$data = @()

foreach ($sub in $subs) {

    Select-AzureSubscription -Name $sub.SubscriptionName

    $services = Get-AzureService -ErrorAction Silentlycontinue
    foreach ($service in $services){

        $VMs = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $service.ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if($null -eq $VMs)
        {
            $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $service.ServiceName -Slot "Production" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
             if($deployment -ne $null) {
                $osVersionCmdlet = Get-AzureRole -ServiceName $service.ServiceName | select OSVersion

                $data += CreateCustomObject -Subscription $sub.SubscriptionName -cloudServiceName $service.ServiceName -osVersion $osVersionCmdlet


                }
        }
    }
}

######################################################################

$timestamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss")
$date= (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yy")
$newPath = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\mypath\$date" -Force

$localfile = "$newPath\OSFamily_$timestamp.csv"

$data | Sort Subscription | Export-Csv -Path $localfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You'll probably need a calculated property for this. Show us the code that now generates the CSV file so we can help you. (sanitize confidential information of course)

Comment: Added in the PS code relating to the data and CSV.

Comment: `$osVersionCmdlet = Get-AzureRole … | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OSVersion`

Answer (score 0):

Just added -ExpandProperty to where the $OsVersionCmdlet line is and got what I needed. Thanks JosefZ!